# How to install WordPress offline?

Tags: wordpress, offline

I don't have internet on my PC. And I have WordPress downloaded. So,can I install WordPress offline? And if I install WordPress on another computer and took it to my machine, will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a Windows machines, you could easily setup a local server using [WAMP](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Then [download the WordPress](https://wordpress.org/latest.zip) and install it on your local server. Going offline only cause you trouble if your theme or plugins is using any CDN or depends on another server for accessing the resources. Say for example, if your theme is using Bootstrap framework, there's a high chance that the developer might have used a CDN to speed up the loading. In such cases, there's a need for internet, if not available would show broken layout or something when you try to access the website from your local server.

Regarding installation of WordPress on another PC and copying it back, yes you can do it and will work. Keep in mind, you need to copy both the files and database. And needs a couple of things to be changed:

1. **Site URL**. Eg: the other PC's local url might be `http://localhost/abcwordpress/` and you might have setup in `http://localhost/test/`. In that case, the site URL needs to be changed. You can change it in `wp_options` table in your database(after you import the database that copied from the other PC).
2. **Absolute URLs**. Sometimes, certain plugins stores the full urls in database. So even after you changed the site url, certain urls in the page would fail. Means, it would be still pointing to the other PC's url (eg: `http://localhost/abcwordpress/`) In such cases, you need to do an entire search and replace to replace the URLs in database. For this, you could try using a plugin like [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/). And some slider or drag & drop content building plugins provides their own version of tool for searching and replacing urls. As they might store the URLs in a different way. So you have to use that too.
3. **Database credentials**. If you are copying the files, the `wp-config.php` would have the database credentials (db name, db username, db user password) different. Make sure you change it with that of the db in your PC's.
4. **Directory name in hataccess**. Sometimes, the `htaccess` file in the main folder would have the folder name in it. Eg:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abcwordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abcwordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here, the `abcwordpress` might be the foldername. So if you are storing it in a different folder (and the url to access is like this : `http://localhost/test/` , then you would have to change it to :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

I think I covered the major things that you have to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress installation is a quick and easy process with just one click away. It will take a few minutes to have WordPress running on your local computer. Let’s start installing WordPress.
Step 1: XAMPP Installation
Firstly, you must download and configure ‘XAMPP’ or ‘WAMP’ on your computer. To create a localhost environment, you required Xampp or Wamp. Here we will use XAMPP, which you can also download from this link: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html and install by the step-by-step wizard.

Install WordPress

After installing XAMPP, open the XAMPP Control Panel from the Start menu. Then start two modules: Apache and MySQL.
Install WordPress
Step 2: Download WordPress
In step 2, download the latest version of ‘WordPress’ from Blog Tool, Publishing Platform, and CMS – WordPress.org

Install WordPress
As a result, a Zip folder of WordPress will be downloaded to your computer.  Extract that zip folder. For extracting zip folders, the WinRar software should be installed on your computer.
Installing WordPress on localhost
In the next step, rename the extracted WordPress folder to any other name (like your project name) because when you create multiple websites, you have to use a separate WordPress folder for each website. So, if you have the same WordPress folder for each website then you won’t remember which folder is for which website. That’s why it is important to rename a WordPress folder for each website to prevent name conflicts.
installation on computer
We have renamed the WordPress folder to the project-name folder.
wordpress installation
Copy the project-name folder. Navigate to the folder where Xampp is installed. Open the XAMPP folder
xampp on computer
Go to the htdocs folder which is a subfolder of the xampp folder. Secondly, paste the project-name folder inside the htdocs folder.
wordpress installation
Step 3: Create a Database
Now, it is time to create a database for your website. To do that, you have to launch phpMyAdmin by clicking on the Admin button from the XAMPP control panel. The admin button is in the second column of the MySQL module.

installation of wordpress on computer
In the next step, create a new database with project-name. The database name should be the same as your project folder name which you have renamed. A database is a place where your website data is stored in the form of tables.

database configuration
Step 4: Run Installation Wizard
You can visit your website here: http://localhost/project-name/

An installation wizard will appear. You must complete that wizard step by step. Firstly, you have to select the language for your website from the language selection list. Secondly, click on the continue button to proceed.

For full detailed information Read my article here"https://beblogy.com/wordpress/how-to-install-wordpress-on-localhost/"

Answer (score -1):

Hi there are 5 simple steps

Download and Install xampp to our computer,
Create a database in your
localhost, Download wordpress zip file from the official site,
Place your wordpress directory in htdocs folder,
Install the wordpress CMS

Please refer the link
https://dev-404.com/wordpress/how-to-install-wordpress-on-my-localhost-2022/

Comment: If you’re going to link to your own website, you need to mention that in your answer otherwise it will be considered spam. Your answer is also bordering on being a link-only answer which might lead to it’s deletion. You must add all relevant text to the answer itself.

Comment: how is this better than the already provided answer?